# In Spock framework, how do I access data table variable from "error" listener?

Tags: groovy, listener, spock, data-driven-tests

I have a test with a data table, e.g. like this:

```
@Unroll
"Basic session start on platform = #platform"() {
    when: "user stats a session on a platform"
    def response = startSession(platform, id) // it does a REST request

    then: "response contains a userId"
    assert verifyUserId(response.userId) // method verifies userId with an internal algorithm and returns true\false if it is valid or not

    where:
    id | platform
    1  | "Facebook"
    2  | "Google"
    3  | "Apple"
}
```

I have also wrote a listener for errors.

```
class MyListener extends AbstractListener {
...
   public void error(ErrorInfo error) { ... }
...
}
```

So that in case an assertion error happens during test execution, the code goes into this "error" method.

The question is, how can I get values of variables from the "where" block from inside the "error" method?

I don't do direct assertions for the data table variables, so ErrorInfo.Exception does not contain them.

I also could not find any other suitable members of the "ErrorInfo" object - I can only find variable names in ErrorInfo.getMethod().getFeature(), but not their values that were there when the error happened.

Comment: Could you please provide a full sample specification?

Comment: I've provided a full sample of the feature method - is that what you meant? Specification just wraps it in a class, it doesn't have any setups\cleanups in my case even.

Comment: [It](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/47270731) (click on _It_ - link is there)  works however no idea if it's what you're looking for and if it's thread safe - try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that ErrorInfo doesn't provide current spec instance, that's why you can't get iteration variables. So I would suggest two ways:

First one is to use iteration interceptor:

```
class ListenForErrorsExtension implements IGlobalExtension {

    void visitSpec(SpecInfo specInfo) {
        specInfo.addListener(new Listener())
        specInfo.allFeatures*.addIterationInterceptor(new IMethodInterceptor() {                      
            @Override
            void intercept(IMethodInvocation invocation) {
                holder.put(invocation.iteration.dataValues)
                invocation.proceed()
            }

        })
    }
```

The second one was kindly suggested in comments by Opal. You could instantinate not `AbstractRunListener`, but `IRunListener`

```
class ErrorExtension implements IGlobalExtension{
....
    @Override
    void beforeIteration(IterationInfo iteration) {       
        holder.put(iteration.dataValues)
    }
....
}
```

It gives you access to each iterration, but the main idea is still following:

You have to create thread safe holder, put iterration data to it BEFORE error happened and then extract.

Comment: Thank you! I have used the iteration interceptor. Instead of holder I have created an Object variable in my listener, and assigned value (dataValues) to it within the intercept method - after that I used it in "error". As far as I understand (I'm total noob btw) I don't really need a thread safe holder, since listener is created per spec, and in our case specs run in 1 thread.

Comment: @Ubeogesh hope it helps :D Btw it always depends, but usually people try to reduce tests regression time by running it in several threads. That's why I've suggested thread safe.

Comment: we do run tests in several threads - however they are paralleled by spec (and each spec has it's own listener\iterationInterceptor)